# Replace the numbers with *

Tags: javascript

How to replace the last two digits with asterisks using JavaScript
Example: `console.log(Math.random()) // 0.6334249899746089 || 0.63342498997460**`
I gave you as an example random

Comment: There are many ways. What have you tried? Please see [ask] and add your attempt to your post.

Comment: @isherwood, I asked the right question.

Comment: Have you put any effort to solve it by yourself?  
Stackoverflow community suppose that you've tried something before ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the last 2 digits with some characters, firstly convert it to a string and then, using the `slice()` method, append the characters. You can read more about the `slice()` method in its [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```js
let numberAsString = Math.random().toString(); //your number as a string
let result = numberAsString.slice(0, -2) + '**'; //cut and append your asterisks
```